# Creating RAID5 with Cisco 12G SAS Modular Raid Controller

Tags: raid, cisco-ucs

On a Cisco UCS C220-M4 I have 3 450GB disks and I want to create a RAID5 with those.

My RAID controller is Cisco 12G SAS Modular Raid Controller.

On the CIMC page for the server though, I only have the option to create RAID1, RAID0, or RAID10. Nowhere can I create a RAID5 virtual drive.

Is this normal? Is it a limitation of my RAID controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [supported RAID levels](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/c/hw/C220M4/install/C220M4/raid.html)  for that controller depend on the amount of modular flash-based write cache that is installed.

Without any write cache only RAID levels 0, 1 and 10 are supported.